# Modelica units of measurement with square root

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

In Modelica I'm trying to define a dedicated data type `OrifSizingCoeff` for the sizing coefficient on an hydraulic orifice.
The corresponding physical quantity is a volumetric flow rate divided by the square root of a pressure, therefore:

a) In SI units: `m3/s` divided by `sqrt(Pa)`;

b) In "practical" units: `l/min` divided by `sqrt(bar)`.

I defined the data type as follows:

```
type OrifSizingCoeff = Real(
    final quantity="Orifice sizing coefficient",
    final unit="m3/(s.Pa(1/2))",
    displayUnit="l/(min.bar(1/2))");
```

I don't get any parsing error but the unit conversion doesn't work (parameter value doesn't change going from one unit to the other); the same happens if I replace `(1/2)` with:

- `0.5`
- `05`

Instead, if I replace `(1/2)` with:

- `(0.5)`
- `0,5`
- `(0,5)`
- `^(1/2)`
- `^(0.5)`

I get a parsing error. (I tried any crazy thing I could think of).

And, if I replace `(1/2)` with `1/2`, a conversion is executed but it's "wrong". (According to Modelica's syntax, `Pa1/2` is interpreted as `(Pa1)/2 = Pa/2`; same for `bar1/2`. Therefore the two units correspond to `m3/(s.Pa/2)` and `l/(min.bar/2)`, respectively).

Is there a way to correctly define the units I need?

Comment: also see: https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/376

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no solution according to the Modelica specification, since unit_exponent is defined to be a signed integer (and cannot be in parenthesis and ^ for exponentiation is not allowed) in section 19.1 of Modelica 3.4.

The goal of the unit-definition in Modelica is to conform to "The International System of Units (SI)" and I could not find any decision about non-integer exponents. (And since they are normally written with superscripts it is less of an issue.)

Comment: Why not use the "squared paramter" with a name "flow_coeff_squared" with units (m³/s)² divided by Pa?

Comment: Here is a helpful example for "squared parameter":  http://unitsofmeasure.org/trac/ticket/51