# Can't represent a variable on openmodelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to create a variable with these unit: `((rad/s)/((N/m)^0.5))`

I've tried many settings but it still doesn't work.

That's my last try:

```
  Real Cap_fact (quantity = "CapacityFactor", unit = "((rad/s)/((N/m)^0.5))");
```

I've tried also with:

```
  Real Cap_fact (final unit = ((rad/s)/((N/m)^0.5)));
```

Comment: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/376

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491466/modelica-units-of-measurement-with-square-root

Comment: similar question, with an idea for a solution: https://ucum.org/trac/ticket/51

Answer (score 5):

Square roots are not supported in unit definitions, since you must use integers as exponents.

The Modelica Specifications defines in chapter [19.1 The Syntax of Unit Expressions](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/unit-expressions.html#the-syntax-of-unit-expressions):

```
 unit_factor:
  unit_operand [ unit_exponent ] 

 unit_exponent:
   [ "+" | "-" ] integer

The SI standard uses super-script for the exponentation, and does thus 
not define any operator symbol for exponentiation. A unit_factor 
consists of a unit_operand possibly suffixed by a possibly signed 
integer number, which is interpreted as an exponent.
```

Note that you also have to remove the character `^` when you define an exponent.